# Hoping for a POST as opposed to GET on sort selection

Tags: forms, google-analytics

So, in my Magento code I have the following in the product list toolbar:

```
    <div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                <?php if($_order=='Price High to Low'): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php elseif($_order=='Price Low to High'): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php elseif($_order=='Price'): ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

It works fine, with one small exception. It adds `?dir=asc&order=price` to the end of the query when selecting "Price Low to High". The problem here is that our SEO team says that Google will count this as a distinct page from the original, and therefore drop us down in rankings due to having differing pages with identical content.

Is there any way to SEND this information via `$_POST` as opposed to `$_GET` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the select in a form that has as inputs the current sort order and sort and when changing the select, just submit the form.
But this is a wrong approach from the user experience point of view.
Users won't be able to bookmark or share links for a certain sorted page.
I'm sure there is a way to tell Google that is the same page opposed to sacrifice the user experience.

Comment: +1 for UX, it's important your users are able to share, say someone is looking for black jeans in size 38, they might share to their friends and say "hey look, I've found a perfect selection of size 38 black jeans on site X" and give their friend a direct link with all the filters "pre-filled"